# Webpack cant parse fake-indexeddb

Tags: reactjs, webpack, indexeddb

I am using fake-indexeddb to unit test my indexeddb implementation in a react app. The unit test runs well.
When I run the project the webpack shows below erorr
[image]

But the build is successful in the end and everything works as intended. What should I do to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late reply, maybe it helps others with a similar issue. It seems to be fixed in version 4.0.1 (https://github.com/dumbmatter/fakeIndexedDB/releases/tag/v4.0.1). You can try to update to the latest version.